# FB.ui / Publish Stream Issue

Tags: javascript, facebook

I am trying to publish a simple stream to facebook from my clients website, using FB.ui, but when I run the "streamPublish" method holding this code I just get "An error occurred. Please try again later."

My code is as follows:-

```
<head>
 <title>A Dynamic Comment System</title>
 <meta http-equiv="content-type" 
  content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css" />

 <!-- Javascript Librairys -->
 <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/commentsystem.js"></script>

 <!-- Style Sheets -->
 <style type="text/css" media="all">
  @import "css/commentstyles.css";
 </style> 

  <script> 
           window.fbAsyncInit = function() { 
    FB.init({appId: "180166762023187", status: true, cookie: true, 
                xfbml: true}); 
            }; 

   (function() 
   { 
    var e = document.createElement("script"); e.async = true; 
    e.src = document.location.protocol + "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"; 
    document.getElementById("fb-root").appendChild(e); 
   }());

   function streamPublish()
   {       
    FB.ui(  
      {   method: 'stream.publish',display:'popup', message: 'getting educated about Facebook Connect', attachment: 
       {      
        name: 'Connect', caption: 'The Facebook Connect JavaScript SDK', description: ('A small JavaScript library that allows you to harness ' +  'the power of Facebook, bringing the user\'s identity, ' + 'social graph and distribution power to your site.'),
        href: 'http://github.com/facebook/connect-js'     
       },  action_links: [{ text: 'Code', href: 'http://github.com/facebook/connect-js' }],     
        user_message_prompt: 'Share your thoughts about Connect'   
      },   
      function(response) 
      {     
       if (response && response.post_id) 
       {       
        alert('Post was published.');     
       } 
       else 
       {       
        alert('Post was not published.');     
       }   
      } );
   } 
   </script> 
</head>
```

I am not all that familiar with the FB API, so I am totally stumped - any help much appreciated ! :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I put the FB.init in the window.fbAsyncInit but when I was refreshing the page, it is was showing me an error. I've solved it by putting the FB.init in the javascript that was calling the the onclick event as well

```
FB.init({appId: "12345", status: true, cookie: true, 
            xfbml: true}); 
FB.ui(
  {
method: 'feed',
name: 'WIN A TRIP TO NYC!',
```

hopefully it will work for you :)

Answer (score 0):

I read that this can happen if the FB.ui is called before the FB.init finishes.   I am having the problem also and putting the FB.init in my onload function is helping but not completely fixing the problem.  I hope this helps you.